# Convert an Array Object that is a String

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have string that looks something like this:

```
var stringArray = "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]"
```

I need to convert it using javascript so it is like this:

```
var actualArray = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

How would one achieve this?

Comment: `var actualArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);`

Comment: yes JSON.parse works. thank you.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your input is structured as `JSON`. You can thus simply use any `JSON` parsing method or library. For example `JSON.parse(stringArray)` ([documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)).

Here is a snippet which uses `JSON.parse`:

```js
var stringArray = "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]";
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);

$('#first').html(parsedArray[0].toString());
$('#second').html(parsedArray[1].toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First element: <span id="first"></span><br>
Second element: <span id="second"></span>
```

---

You can also use the `eval` function ([documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)) but please note that you should avoid that function at all cost if possible. It is dangerous and often slower than its alternatives. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is more on that.

However here is a version using the `eval` method:

```js
var stringArray = "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]";
var parsedArray = eval(stringArray);

$('#first').html(parsedArray[0].toString());
$('#second').html(parsedArray[1].toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First element: <span id="first"></span><br>
Second element: <span id="second"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift replies , both eval() and JSON.parse work great.

Comment: [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) should only be used when absolutely needed. Any values used must be sanitized.

Comment: @AlanLarimer Thanks for the link, I've edited the answer, included it and changed the order of suggestions.